# How to backup and restore Firefox bookmarks from command line?

Tags: command-line, firefox, backup, bookmarks

Is there an easy way to backup Firefox bookmarks to a file with command line. Running a find command, I managed to find this file: `/.mozilla/firefox/9a5j5dbb.default/bookmarkbackups/bookmarks-2013-05-22.json` which appears to have my latest data. However, I dont know if the folder under Firefox (currently 9a5j5dbb.default) will keep changing, and I'm pretty sure the date will.

Rather than a more advanced shell script to dynamically calculate the path based on today's date and looking for the only xxxxx.default folder under `~/.mozilla`.

Is there a simpler/more-robust way to save/copy your current Firefox bookmarks to a specified file?

Comment: The folder named `9a5j5dbb.default` is the Profile Folder of your Firefox. It won't change unless you re-install Firefox/Ubuntu. If you delete this folder, Firefox would create another randomly-generated-named folder for your Profile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well since there is only one `.default` in that folder you could use a wildcard like this:

`*.default`

`sudo cp -fr /Path/to/Source/Folder/*.default /Path/to/Destination/Folder`

Comment: This seems like the most appropriate answer so far because I can run it from the shell. I guess I just have to use this and pick the alphanumeric .json file to get the latest one. I was rather hoping I could run something like firefox --dump-bookmarks /my/folder/loc/bookmarks.json

Comment: It's not necesary to use sudo as the profile folder is in $HOME. If sudo is used to make the copy, root will own the copied files, unless you of course used the -a switch with cp to preserve ownership.

Answer (score 16):

## Using sqlite:

Firefox uses `sqlite` to store its data. Bookmarks are stored in `~/.mozilla/firefox/profile_name/places.sqlite`. So we can use `sqlite` to backup and restore Firefox bookmarks.

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following command to install `sqlite3`:

```
apt-get install sqlite3
```

Now you can one following command to backup/restore Firefox bookmarks, make sure to close Firefox before running any of following commands.

**Backup:**

```
sqlite3 ~/.mozilla/firefox/user.profile/places.sqlite ".backup /path/to/directory"
```

**Restore:**

```
sqlite3 ~/.mozilla/firefox/user.profile/places.sqlite ".restore /path/to/backup/file"
```

Change `user.profile` with your default profile name.

## Simple Backup:

If you don't want to install any additional packages use following command to copy latest bookmarks backup from Firefox profile:

```
cp $(find ~/.mozilla/firefox/fvy8ug06.default/bookmarkbackups | sort | tail -n1) .
```

Comment: Whilst this is probably the most 'proper' way to do things in the command shell, I still prefer Mr Seeds solution for 3 main reasons:
1) This rquired me to install sqlite3
2) This saved in a non-human readable format rather than the json format fo the other solution
3) This command was far less 'flexible' and I had to plug in an absolute path name for sqlite to work. Something like ~/data did not work.
However, thank you for your input, and perhaps others will prefer to use this solution.

Comment: @Programster - I suppose that, by "Mr Seeds" you mean Gaurav Sharma, because only him is the one who posted the JSON-related answer. I suppose also that he must have been changed his name/alias after your comment.

Comment: +1 for the Simple Backup solution which includes "copy the latest json file".

Comment: You can also just make a copy of `~/.mozilla/firefox/user.profile/places.sqlite`, without using sqlite's `.backup`

Answer (score 3):

- Working solution as of 30/10/2022

Set `browser.bookmarks.autoExportHTML` to true in `about:config` or `user.js`.
This will generate a `bookmarks.html` file in your Firefox profiles' root directory eg. `/home/snowman/.mozilla/firefox/0uffvdebh.default` whenever the **browser is closed**.

See the Mozilla Support page for more information. [Export all the bookmarks from a loads of profiles from a script](https://support.mozilla.org/mk/questions/1374791)

This file can be copied and imported as expected.

Comment: It doesn't generate any `bookmarks.html` here, only a `bookmarkbackups` folder, with `.jsonlz4` files inside of it that i don't know how to open (7z seems not to be able to open them). Firefox 106.0.4.

Comment: Hi @robertspierre. It does work for me. I have ```Mozilla Firefox 106.0.5``` on Artix Linux. Note that the file is only generated when you close firefox.

Comment: Worked flawless - thanks @rial & also for the hint that its only generated after closing Firefox

Answer (score -3):

In mozilla there is a option for taking the Backup of Bookmarks in JSON format.

You can follow these steps:-

1. open all bookmarks (shift+ctrl+o)
2. select 'Import and Backup' option (alt+i)
3. Select 'Backup' option

here you can get all bookmark backup in json format.

Comment: -1 That's not from command line